# ARRAY ACCESS AND INSERTION RECORD DATABASE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would need to access the array to retrieve the information and insert it into the database (Code, Customer, Phone1, Phone2). Someone can help me?

```
    {
    :recordset => {
        :row => [

            [0] {
                :property => [
                    [0] {
                    :name => "Code",
                    :value => "C0001"
                    },
                    [1] {
                    :name => "Customer",
                    :value => "ROSSI MARIO"
                    },
                    [2] {
                    :name => "Phone1",
                    :value => "1234567890"
                    }
                ]
            },

            [1] {
                :property => [
                    [0] {
                    :name => "Code",
                    :value => "C0002"
                    },
                    [1] {
                    :name => "Customer",
                    :value => "VERDE VINCENT"
                    },
                    [2] {
                    :name => "Phone1",
                    :value => "9876543210"
                    },
                    [3] {
                    :name => "Phone2",
                    :value => "2468101214"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    :@xmlns => "http://localhost/test"
    }
```

p.s. The Phone2 value during the SOAP call is only displayed if it is present in an archive

Thank you

Comment: What is this structure `:row => [0]{ ... }, [1]{ ... }`?

Comment: It comes from a SOAP call

Comment: @AntonioFalcetta You have tagged this question as `ruby`, but `:row => [0]{ ... }, [1]{ ... }` is not valid `ruby`. What is that structure supposed to be, in `ruby`?

Answer (score 0):

Your data doesn't look like a valid ruby structure. Once you are able to convert it to be more ruby-like, you can make use of [`each_with_object`](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object) to generate a well formatted set of attributes and their values from your data:

```
data
 => {:recordset=>{
      :row=>[{
        :property=>[
          {:name=>"Code", :value=>"C0001"},
          {:name=>"Customer", :value=>"ROSSI MARIO"},
          {:name=>"Phone1", :value=>"1234567890"}
        ]
      }, {
        :property=>[
          {:name=>"Code", :value=>"C0002"},
          {:name=>"Customer", :value=>"VERDE VINCENT"},
          {:name=>"Phone1", :value=>"9876543210"},
          {:name=>"Phone2", :value=>"2468101214"}
        ]
      }]
    },
    :@xmlns=>"http://localhost/test"}


data.keys
 => [:recordset, :@xmlns] 

data[:recordset][:row].count
 => 2    # There are 2 set of attribute-value pairs


result = data[:recordset][:row].each_with_object([]) do |hash, out|
           out << hash[:property].each_with_object({}) do |h, o|
                    o[h[:name]] = h[:value]
                  end
         end
 => [{"Code"=>"C0001", "Customer"=>"ROSSI MARIO", "Phone1"=>"1234567890"},
     {"Code"=>"C0002", "Customer"=>"VERDE VINCENT", "Phone1"=>"9876543210", "Phone2"=>"2468101214"}]
```

Now, you can iterate over `result` and create respective records in database.

Comment: How can I populate the customers table with all the records of the array?

simple example:

Customer.create(Code: 'Code', Customer: 'Customer', Phone1: 'Phone1' Phone2: 'Phone2')

Comment: I have no idea about your models and database schema. I would suggest going through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#create and try on your own.

Comment: If the array returns only one record, the following console message appears:


TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

{
    :recordset => {
        :row => {
            :property => [
                [ 0] {
                     :name => "Code",
                    :value => "C0001"
                },
                [ 1] {
                     :name => "Customer",
                    :value => "ROSSI MARIO"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
       :@xmlns => "http://localhost/test"
}

Comment: Try replacing `data[:recordset][:row]` with `Array(data[:recordset][:row])`